# Explorer tab is disabled in SQL Server 2016 Master Data Services

Tags: sql-server, master-data-services

I have installed Master Data services in SQL Server 2016. I configured the Master Data Service properly. It can appear in web browser. I have installed Sliverlight and Master Data Services Add-In For Microsoft Excel as well. Still when I open the MDS in web browser the explorer and Integration Management tab is disabled.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently nothing to explore or import/export data from.  That is why those buttons are disabled.  To enable them you must create some models and define entities & hierarchies within the models.  This is all done in the System Administration section of MDS.  Once you have created these objects the buttons will enable.

The following link should help you get started: [Getting Started (Master Data Services)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633731(v=sql.105).aspx)